# Javascript random number picker not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a simple javascript application to pick a random number between 1 and a number I specify in an input field, so I can pick a random winner for a Christmas competition.

Below is the code I've got so far. I don't think it can be far off, can you help me as it's not updating the input field to display the random number:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  function randomWinner() {
    var topNumber = topNumber.value;    
    var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random() + topNumber);
    winningNumber.value=randomnumber;
    return true;
  }
</script>

<form name="selectWinner">
Pick random number between 1 and <input name="topNumber" value="100"><br /><br />
The winning number: <input name="winningNumber" readonly="true"><br /><br />
<input type="button" value="Pick Winner" OnClick="randomWinner();">
</form>
```

Comment: I don't understand why the input field is not updating. I appreciate also the randomNumber line is also incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access the input field just by using its name. Try adding an ID and using `getElementById`:

```
<input name="topNumber" id="topNumber" value="100">
<input name="winningNumber" id="winningNumber" readonly="true">
```

JavaScript:

```
function randomWinner() {
    var topNumberInput = document.getElementById('topNumber');
    var topNumber = parseInt(topNumberInput.value, 10);
    var randomnumber= 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * topNumber);
    var winningNumber = document.getElementById('winningNumber');
    winningNumber.value=randomnumber;
    return true;
}
```

In addition, I've used `parseInt` to make sure were working with a proper number.

Working example: http://jsbin.com/uwude4

Answer (score 3):

You need to multiply your *topNumber*  with the random number between 0 and 1:

```
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random() * topNumber);
```

And to get a random integer of a specific range:

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a string value to the random number, which gives you for example `0.98764912837465 + "100"` which gives you the string `"0.98764912837465100"`. The `floor` function manages to turn it back into a string, but it's still never large enough to become anything other than zero.

You need to multiply instead. That gives you a number in the range 0 to topnumber-1, so you have to add one to get it in the range 1 to topnumber:

```
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random() * topNumber) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to multiply the `topNumber` but you have to increase the `topNumber + 1`, to include the range, so `topNumber = 101` results in a maximum `randomNumber` of 100.

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * topNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Math.random()` generates a number between 0 and 1. Here is what you need:

```
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*topNumber)+1;
```

Math.random() will generate a value in range `[0..1]`. `[0..1]` multiplied on `topNumber` will result in `[0..topNumber]` range. However, the `Math.floor()` will limit it to `[0..(topNumber-1)]`. Now we add 1 and get `[1..topNumber]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
            var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*n)
```

This will give u a random no between 0 to n..